# How to add multiple Objects in Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Every time I click the "Add to Cart button" it will update the `cartarray[]`. What I want to do is to add a new object in the cart for every click so that I can have multiple objects for every different Cart item.

```js
(function() {
  const cartbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".add_to_cart_button");

  cartbtn.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if (event.target.parentElement.classList.contains("add_to_cart_button")) {
        let fullpath = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0].children[0].src;
        const item = {};
        item.img = fullpath;
        let name = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[3].children[0].textContent;
        item.name = name;
        let price = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[3].children[1].textContent;
        let finalprice = price.slice(1).trim();
        item.price = finalprice;
        const cartarray = [];
        var product = function(name, price, img) {
          this.name = name
          this.price = price
          this.img = img
        };
        cartarray.push(new product(name, finalprice, fullpath));
        console.log(cartarray);

      }
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="product-item men">
  <div class="product discount product_filter">
    <div class="product_image">
      <img src="images/product_1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="favorite favorite_left"></div>
    <div class="product_bubble product_bubble_right product_bubble_red d-flex flex-column align-items-center"><span>-$20</span></div>
    <div class="product_info">
      <h6 id="item-name" class="product_name"><a href="single.html">Fujifilm X100T 16 MP Digital Camera (Silver)</a></h6>
      <div class="product_price">$520.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red_button add_to_cart_button"><a href="#/">add to cart</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share html code as well

Comment: So what is specific problem with code shown? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: i have added an event listener to a button called "add to cart" which take three values from HTML (Name,price and path for image) with the help of DOM. after taking these values it saves those three values in an array called "cartarray" now problem is that every time i click "ad to cart" it saves three values for that product which i clicked, and when i click on next product it simply updates previous values of "cartarray" with new ones. all i want is to save all three values of every product that i click in array "cartarray"

Comment: put `const catarray = []` definition before the `cartbtn.forEach`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`cartarray` should be declared outside of the `addEventListener` in order for the items in the cart to be persistent.

I would also suggest to place the creation of the product outside as well, although technically this is not required.

See the following as an example where the `for` loop is simulating your button clicks:

```
const cartarray = [];
const product = function(name, price, img) {
  return {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    img: img
  }
};

for (let x = 1; x < 6; x++) {
  cartarray.push(new product('p' + x, x + '.00', 'path/to/img' + x + 'png'));  
}


console.log(cartarray);
```

Comment: thank you very much but it still is doing same. i want to save every product i click in same Array so that i can save it in Local Storage. but method you describe still save every product i click in different array.

Comment: `new product` when you are using factory design pattern

Comment: SORRY MY BAD. i was doing something wrong . your method worked. Thank You very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I leave an answer rather than a comment because I still don't have the reputation to leave a comment. Provide the HTML code, as my colleagues said and we'll be able to answer. 
Something 'fishy' I notice that may stop your code to work are these two lines of code:

```
const cartbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".add_to_cart_button"); 
if (event.target.parentElement.classList.contains("add_to_cart_button"))
```

It may be the '.' in the first line, or missing in the second line which stops your code working. I may be wrong, it's just an assumption without seeing your full code

Comment: No the Code does not give any kind of error. and HTML file is very long i don't think i can post that here.